# jHipster Vue: Where to modify the base URL for calling the backend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jhipster

Question: So I started grokking Vue+Spring Boot flavor of jHipster these days, made a public API to parse some products, but it doesn't seem like the Vue frontend is able to fetch the backend data... what is the base URL that was used to call the backend (because I made a service class on Vue based on the service class from entities, but there's no clarity which base url is it calling)? It doesn't seem like it's localhost 8080 from the Vue frontend. What do I need to do so that the Vue frontend can call the backend?

More info, I started the project as a monolith.

Comment: I use Angular not Vue with JHipster but if it's the same, it does not specify host and port for backend it just uses /api on same server that served the frontend js bundle.

Answer (score 0):

webpack.common.js

is the file that is use during development for proxying. From localhost:9060 routed to localhost:8080.